# Unable to redirect from http to https

Tags: apache2, ssl, redirect

Im sure this question got answered above a hundred times (cause i nearly have read them all), but i cant get my apache2 redirection working.

Im a total beginner regarding everything on linux and im currently trying to get a website running.
The site is already available under https and has a certificate.

[bad request on port 80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUR7N.png)

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 80
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomainname.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost <mydomainname>:443
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName <mydomainname>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTPS_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName <mydomainname>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        SSLEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

I also already executed `sudo a2ensite <mydomainname>.conf` if this is important.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some important directives in the :443 `VirtualHost`. The SSL certificate file and private key are not specified.

The `VirtualHost`directive should look like the following:

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/www.example.com.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/www.example.com.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

Check the official [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html) for more details:

Comment: https is working, my problem is the redirection from http to https, which throws "bad request" on visiting the site. I changed the config and added your settings, nothing changed so far.